# Get HID code of pressed keyboard button in Java

Tags: java, string, keyboard, hid

Please give me advice how I can retrieve the HID code of any pressed button on the keyboard. (Java)

The purpose is, when somebody prints any language, say french or spanish, I need to get the exact English qwerty chars that represent the printed "any language" string. For example, a French dude writes "WQA" in French layout, which is actually pressing "ZAQ" on the English layout keyboard. Well, I need to get the input "WQA" (knowing it is French) and realize that it was pressed by English qwerty "ZAQ" buttons.

Hope I was clear enough.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the corresponding char of the pressed key, you can use KeyEvent. getKeyChar()

Comment: But, with typing french keyboard, I will get the french char, while I am asking for the HID code in order to get the English char that is also treated by this button.